# Spark Parquet Partitioning: How to choose a key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I find that by default, Spark seem to write many small parquet files. I think it maybe better if I use partitioning to reduce this?

But how do I choose a partition key? For example, for a users dataset which I frequently query by ID do I partition by `id`? But I am thinking, will it create 1 parquet file for 1 user in that case?

What if I frequently query by 2 keys but only 1 or the other not both at the same time, is it useful to partition by both keys? For example, lets say I query usually by `id` and `country`, do I use `partitionBy('id', 'country')`?

If there is no specific pattern in which I query the data but want to limit the number of files, do I use `repartition` then?

Comment: The output of `partitionBy` is different from `repartition`. `partitionBy` helps you to create a hive-like partitioned table structure. `repartition` on the other hand, lets you change the number of partitions of your dataframe that is equal to the number of files that will get written. You can also pass a column name to `repartition`.

Comment: If I pass a column name to repartition does it mean 1 get 1 file for each unique value in that column? @philantrovert

Comment: That and the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. if the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is greater than the distinct values of given column ,you will get empty partitions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Partitions create a subdirectory for each value of the partition field, so if you are filtering by that field, instead of reading every file it will read only the files in the appropiate subdirectory.

- You should partition when your data is too large **and** you usually
  work with a subset of the data at a time.
- You should partition by a field that you both need to filter by
  frequently **and** that has low cardinality, i.e: it will create a
  relatively small amount of directories with relatively big amount of
  data on each directory.

You don't want to partition by a unique id, for example. It would create lots of directories with only one row per directory; this is very inefficient the moment you need to select more than one id.

Some typical partition fields could be dates if you are working with time series (daily dumps of data for instance), geographies (country, branches,...) or taxonomies (types of object, manufacturer, etc).

Comment: I was thinking of dates, but if my date column includes times it will not make sense too? Or isit possible to say it should partition ranges of values together?

Comment: Per the second point, you should group by ranges. It's straightforward to create a string field with just the date from your timestamp (use YYYYMMDD format). If you partition by this new field, you will have a directory for each day. If you then want to select a range from your timestamp, filter by BOTH the new date field AND the timestamp. If you filter only by the original timestamp it will not make use of partitioning and instead will read every directory when searching for valid timestamps.

Comment: Will partitioning help to load all data faster in pandas?

Comment: The comment by @ManuValdés is exactly the right approach, I would like to see that comment expanded into an answer with some additional details/narrative.